# Google Map Javascript API - HTTP Referrer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a page which uses the Google Javascript and Geocoding APIs. I am happy with using a server key for the Geocoding API as this is not visible to the end user.
My understanding is we have to use a browser key while calling the library below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SOMEKEYHERE">
</script>
```

I wish to restrict access to this key but I cannot get the HTTP Referrer to work at all. I have tried the below which end up completely restricting access:

```
*.myexample.com
*myexample.com/*
http://myexample.com
https://myexample.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these two:

```
*.example.com/*
example.com/*
```

Comment: I will try again but I am pretty sure I have already tried this combo..

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: I agree, but the OP was merely asking what to enter in a text box.